# How to enable Over scroll (Bounce animation on page end) in Navigation Drawer itself and how to change the icon's color?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Though I'm trying to build an app with the `Navigation Drawer Activity` from android studio's default `Navigation Drawer Activity`. Everything is working fine on that, but I can't see the `over scroll mode` in my drawer like the **Google play store** app. And also I can't change the image color of the navigation drawer icons (Different colors for each icon).

**So, my first question is :** *How to add the bounce animation in the drawer?*

**And, my second question is :** *How to change the color of the drawer icons?(Different colors for each icon)*

*My codes (Remember one thing that I'm using Android Studio's default Navigation Drawer Activity).*

**-: XML :-**

`activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`activity_main_drawer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="@string/drawer_subtitle_01">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:checkableBehavior="single"
                    android:id="@+id/1st"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_1st"
                    android:title="@string/drawer_1st" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

**-: JAVA :-**

`onCreate`

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

`onClick`

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();
      if (id == R.id.1st) {
         toast.setText("1st option selected");
         toast.show();
      }
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```

**-: Not working methodS :-**

`IconColors`

***01.*** `app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"`

`OverScroll`

***01.*** `android:overScrollMode="always"`

***02.*** `drawer.setOverScrollMode(DrawerLayout.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);`

***03.*** `navigationView.setOverScrollMode(NavigationView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);`

***04.*** `for (int i = 0; i < drawer.getChildCount(); i++) {
drawer.getChildAt(i).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);}`

***05.*** `for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getChildCount(); i++) {
navigationView.getChildAt(i).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);}`

***06.*** `for (int i = 0; i < drawer.getChildCount(); i++) {
drawer.getChildAt(i).setOverScrollMode(DrawerLayout.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);}`

***07.*** `for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getChildCount(); i++) {
navigationView.getChildAt(i).setOverScrollMode(NavigationView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);}`

Answer (score 0):

To change the drawer icon colors back to their original color, just add this code (Kotlin):

```
drawerView.itemIconTintList = null
```

Comment: I want different color in each icon and tell me in java.

Comment: Just use a graphics program to change the color of each icon to a different color.   Then use this line of color to display the original color:  `drawerView.setItemIconTintList(null);`